# For loop and If statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

```
int i;
int[] mArray = new int[5];

for (i = 0; i < mArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number:");
    mArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (mArray[i] >= 50 && mArray[i] <= 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers only between 10 and 50.");
        mArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

}
```

Can't seem to get if statement to work when it has two rules in it   `if (mArray[i] >= 50 && mArray[i] <= 10)`

But it works fine with 1 rule `if (mArray[i] >= 50)`

Comment: How could it work? The condition would be that it is Greater Than 50 but at the same time Lower than 10!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No number can be larger than 50 AND smaller than 10, your condition is wrong:

```
if (mArray[i] >= 50 && mArray[i] <= 10)
```

it should be

```
if (mArray[i] >= 50 || mArray[i] <= 10)
```

Comment: @user2094494: But please read my edited answer as well - even after you've fixed that condition, your code is still broken, as it will allow the user to enter a second bad number and continue.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `||` instead of `&&`

```
mArray[i] >= 50 || mArray[i] <= 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at your condition:

```
if (mArray[i] >= 50 && mArray[i] <= 10)
```

You're trying to find a number which is simultaneously *at least 50* and *at most 10*.

What number did you have in mind that would be considered invalid?

I suspect you meant:

```
if (mArray[i] > 50 || mArray[i] < 10)
```

Note that I've changed `>=` and `<=` to `>` and `<` respectively to match your message - I assume you want 10 or 50 to be valid.

Also note that you're only testing for validity once - if the user persists in entering a second bad number, you'll accept that. I suspect you want something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number:");
int value = Convert.ToInt32(ConsoleReadLine());

while (value > 50 || value < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers only between 10 and 50.");
    value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
// Now we know it's valid, so it's reasonably to put it in the array
mArray[i] = value;
```

Comment: Any number between 50 and 10

Comment: @user2094494: A number greater than 50 *and* less than 10? Can you give any specific example of that? Think very carefully...

Answer (score 4):

Which number is bigger than 50 AND in the same moment smaller then 10? I think you should replace your && (AND) with || (OR)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on *how* you intend to make it work

```
/*Pass if the value is more or equal 50 OR lesst or equal 10*/
mArray[i] >= 50 || mArray[i] <= 10
```

or

```
/*Passs if the value is between 10 and 50, including edges*/
mArray[i] >= 10 && mArray[i] <= 50
```

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is impossible. `myArray[i]` has to be both larger than 50 AND smaller than 10. Did you mean:

```
if (mArray[i] >= 50 || mArray[i] <= 10)
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your logic to:

```
if (mArray[i] >= 50 || mArray[i] <= 10)
```